# i m using url slug for my pages, but i have to manually type the slug , it doesnot appear when i click on the button

Tags: python, django

I am trying to generate different pages but when i click only actual page occurs, but not the one with the values loaded.
but when i manually add the uid in the url , the page appears.

Here is my view,these two are relatable,

```
def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
    return render(request, 'link.html', {"results":results})

def link(request):
    return render(request, 'link.html')
```

Here is my url patterns,

```
 path('link/', views.link, name='link'),
 path('link/<int:uid>', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
```

Here is the models,

```
class AffProduct(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    specification = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sale_price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    img2 = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    promote_method = models.TextChoices
    terms_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    promote_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=promote_choices,
        default='PPC'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my Html part,

```
#What i want to achieve is when i click on 'Get Link', it should redirect to 
path('link/<int:uid>', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
```

but it redirects with no slug data.

```
<span>
   <a class="Update" href="{% url 'link' %}">Get Link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: could you post your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def link(request):
    results = AffProduct.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'link.html', {"results":results})

#link.html
 {% for product in results %}
   <span>
      <a class="Update" href="{% url 'link_view' product.uid %}">Get Link</a>
   </span>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the error i am encountering while trying this method
```
NoReverseMatch at /affiliation/blink_viewproduct/

Reverse for 'link' with arguments '(10001,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['affiliation/link/$']
```

Comment: just update the `<a class="Update" href="{% url 'link_view' product.uid %}">Get Link</a>` it should be `link_view`